# Can uClinux run on the Altera DE2-115?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, uclinux, nios

I'm looking for interesting ways to use my FPGAs (Altera DE2 and DE2-115) and it seems that uClinux includes some files for DE2-115 in its distribution but there is no documentation how to use it. What is the use of the files in the DE2-115 directory if not for running Linux on the DE2-115?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that should be possible and is indeed the purpose of the files in that directory. Johan Granath from the AGSTU School of Higher Vocational Education has a good PDF document describing how to achieve it in detail that includes a simple custom hardware kernel module:

[μClinux on NIOS2 with custom hardware and kernel module](http://uuoc.org/uClinux_nios2_custom_hardware.pdf)

Along similar lines is a publication by David Lariviere and Stephen A. Edwards from 
Columbia University:

[μClinux on the Altera DE2](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/papers/lariviere2008uclinux.pdf)

Comment: Copy of the first link: https://sites.google.com/site/francescosblogg/file-cabinet - uClinux_nios2_custom_hardware.pdf   1363k  v. 1  May 6, 2015, 1:16 PM  Francesco Robino